# overflow-x CSS not working with firefox/IE

Tags: html, css, overflow, selectmanylistbox

I have below code

```
.textareaclasswide{ border:solid 1px #7f9db9; width:460px; height:150px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;overflow-x:auto;  
}



</f:verbatim>
<h:selectManyListbox id="availableProducts" value="#{addSubscriptionsBean.selAvailableProducts}" styleClass="textareaclasswide">
<s:selectItems value="#{addSubscriptionsBean.availableProducts}"var="product" itemLabel="#{product.productDisplayName}" itemValue="#{product.productCode}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
<f:verbatim>
```

i am using selectManyListbox , for which vertical scroll bar is working fine , but if i am including overflow-x in css for horizontal scroll bar its working in chrome but not working in IE/FIREFOX

Please help

Comment: You need to include enough code to reproduce your issue here. Just the CSS of one class is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap;` to enable horizontal scrolling.

```css
.textareaclasswide{ 
  white-space: nowrap;
  border:solid 1px #7f9db9; 
  width:460px; 
  height:150px;
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
  overflow-x:auto;  
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" class="textareaclasswide"  cols="10">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer luctus, neque vel posuere pellentesque, dui orci vehicula erat, in dignissim dolor metus et est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec iaculis faucibus dictum. Sed faucibus dui vitae euismod gravida. Nullam quis est molestie, imperdiet augue vitae, ultricies lorem. Donec consectetur scelerisque nisi, vel dictum enim volutpat id. In consectetur rutrum tempor. Curabitur volutpat, leo a vestibulum facilisis, sapien lectus lacinia ante, ac volutpat dui nibh sed erat.

Etiam vitae lacus in libero consectetur bibendum. Curabitur tincidunt arcu in massa ultrices imperdiet. Phasellus tristique velit vel auctor egestas. Nulla facilisi. Sed auctor turpis at dui consectetur lacinia ut quis ante. Aliquam non nisl est. Maecenas dapibus lectus at libero egestas, ac semper arcu facilisis. Aliquam auctor ex at erat rutrum, vel suscipit felis eleifend. Mauris lobortis diam quis est malesuada, eget placerat turpis sagittis.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , but this is not working for me

Comment: Could you create a jsFidlle or something reproducing the 'not working' behaviour? I may be able to help you then.